# unable to login into my microsoft teams account neither by using chromium nor by using application "microsoft teams for linux"

Tags: microsoft-teams

i am unable to login into my Microsoft teams account neither on chromium nor by using application "Microsoft teams for Linux" although my email and passwords were right as i logged into my account by using same credentials on my mobile.
**OS name :Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
OS TYPE: 64-BIT
Gnome version:3.36.8
windowing system: X11**

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; also package versions maybe helpful.

Comment: OS name :Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
OS TYPE: 64-BIT
 Gnome version:3.36.8
 windowing system: X11

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please first check your date and time and set it to automatic then check if you have selected your time zone correctly.
after that restart your system
then Microsoft teams will run